# how can I use refresh token in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, api

I have completed steps of authorization and obtained the access token and refresh token by Laravel Passport.

My Angular frontend and Laravel backend work fine.

My main questions are:

1. How and when should I use the refresh token to make new access token?
2. Should this be done in the background or should the user have to click on a button to refresh the token?
3. Should the Angular page be reloaded when creating the new token?

Answer (score 1):

I am using JWT authentication in my angular project where the token is set by the API.

The approach I'm taking when the token is expired in explained below -

1. Expose a new API which will take an expired token and return newly created token.
2. The API should check the token expiry in every REST API call.
3. In case, the token  is expired, the API should return a status (as per the standards, 498 - expired/invalid).
4. In angular,create a service layer (token refresher) which delegates every API calls to the server (internally using the http service).
5. The job of this service is to check the status of API response (if it is 498) and internally make an additional call to refresh the token.
6. The service can then re-initiate the original call with newly created token to get the response.
7. All the api services will call the token refresher to get the response.

On a broader level, token refresher is a wrapper over the default http service which performs the additional check.

This will avoid the annoying page loads and make the application faster.

> EDIT - Example of HTTP Interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Observer } from "rxjs/Observer";
import { Response as ApiResponse } from "../../models/base/response.model";
import { ToastModel } from "../../redux/app-reducers";
import { ReducerActions } from "../../redux/reducer-actions";

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    constructor(private _XHRBackend: XHRBackend,
        private _RequestOptions: RequestOptions,
        private _ToastStore: Store<ToastModel>,
        private _LoaderStore: Store<boolean>) {
        super(_XHRBackend, _RequestOptions);
    }

    public request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.handleResponse(super.request(url, options));
    }

    public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        this.beforeRequest(url);
        return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    public post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        this.beforeRequest(url, body);
        return super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    public put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        this.beforeRequest(url, body);
        return super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    public delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        this.beforeRequest(url);
        return super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
    }

    private getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return options;
    }

    private handleResponse(response: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return response
            .catch(this.onCatch)
            .do(this.onSuccess.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this))
            .finally(this.afterResponse.bind(this));
    }

    private beforeRequest(url: string, body?: string): void {
        this._LoaderStore.dispatch({ type: ReducerActions.Loader.Set, payload: true });
    }

    private afterResponse(): void {
        this._LoaderStore.dispatch({ type: ReducerActions.Loader.Set, payload: false });
    }

    private onCatch(error: any, caught: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        console.log("interceptor catch called");
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }

    private onSuccess(res: Response): void {
        let response: ApiResponse<any> = res.json();
        if (!response.message) {
            return;
        }
        let toast: ToastModel = {
            text: response.message,
            duration: 5000,
            type: "success"
        };
        this._ToastStore.dispatch({ type: ReducerActions.Toast.Update, payload: toast });
    }

    private onError(error: any): void {
        let toast: ToastModel = {
            text: "Error occurred!",
            duration: 5000,
            type: "failure"
        };
        this._ToastStore.dispatch({ type: ReducerActions.Toast.Update, payload: toast });
    }
}
```

---

In the above  example, `handleResponse` callback is the hook to do anything you want. (In this case, token refresh API call).

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: From what I'm understanding, your Access Token also acts as a Refresh Token. I don't think this is more secure than saving a Refresh Token on the Client's side no?

Comment: The question is asking the proper use of refresh token to re-generate the access token. In this case we would want to avoid unnecessary page loads and it should be done in the background. The service is just solving those problems. Security is definitely an issue but it is not the concern of the interceptor service. Interceptor service should work smartly to regenerate the access toke using refresh token so that user doesn't have to manually refresh it or experience unwanted page loads :)

Comment: I definitely get the intent. My question was more about why not simply using a Refresh Token? It seems to me that using your Access Token as a RefreshToken poses more security risks than using a RefreshToken saved in the Local Storage (even though this also poses security risks)

Comment: Well your point does make sense! However this solution keeps the authentication part out of the picture. As an example, in this answer, I have illustrated the use of JWT authentication where access token and refresh token is one and the same. In case one is using a different authentication process,  one should definitely come up with a solution that guarantees  you the safety. But as I said earlier, this problem is out of the scope as far as interceptor implementation is concerned. :)